# checking the condition in java leading to error

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

I have the below piece of code in which under if condition I am getting the sonar
findings that is Strings literals should be placed on the left side when checking for equality. Please advise how to overcome this.

```
final String aviid = avcMaster.getAVMaster().getAviiId();
if ((!aviid.equals("44")) || (!aviid.equals("55"))) { // ** Sonar Issue **//
    final String defaultAiId = "88";
    deviceElement.setAttribute("avi", defaultAiId);
}
else{
    deviceElement.setAttribute("avi", aviid);
}
```

Comment: If your `aviid` is not null then `(!aviid.equals("44")) || (!aviid.equals("55"))` is always true.

Comment: also, just so you know: if ((!aviid.equals("44")) || (!aviid.equals("55"))) can you give one example where this will not return true?

Comment: I think you want to use `&&` instead of `||`...

Comment: You probably mean `deviceElement.setAttribute("avi", aviid.matches("44|55")? aviid: "88");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparison between `String` variable and `String`  literal

- calling the method on the variable: if the variable is null you'll get a `NullPointerException`

  ```
  aviid.equals("44")
  ```
- calling the method on the literal: you can't get a NPE and you'll have `false` in case the variable holds `null`

  ```
  "44".equals(aviid)
  ```

Sonar warns you because for it, it's better to get false than `NPE`, but the code is your choice.

---

Also your test is wrong because it'll always be true, as you can't have 44 and 55 at the same time, one of them will be true, you surely meant `&&`, also you'd better do it the other way you wouldn't need the negation.

```
if ((!aviid.equals("44")) && (!aviid.equals("55"))) {
```

And to do it shorter (from comments)

```
deviceElement.setAttribute("avi", aviid.matches("44|55") ? aviid : "88");
```

Comment: That’s correct, but the assumption that getting `false` instead of a `NullPointerException` in case of `null` is better, is questionable.

Comment: @Holger I didn't give opinion on the one to use :)

Comment: I know, Sonarqube does…